# Possible to get value of `__func__` in a constexpr?

Tags: c++, macros, constexpr

I have a macro that calls a constructor with `__func__`.
Is it possible to convert it into a constexpr and still use the "local"/"right" version of **func**?

```cpp
#define LOG_SCOPE_DURATION(category_arg) \
  ScopeDuration __scopeDuration = ScopeDurationConstructor(category_arg, __func__);
```

Comment: An example of what you are trying to do might help, `__func__` is already a `const char*` what are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C++17 or before, you can't convert your macro to a function.
The closest you can get to, is creating a function that accepts the location and uses it.

Please note that macros can create inline variables for you, a function will never add any variables to your current stack frame. So instead, you can add [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) to the function to not ignore your return value.

```
template<typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr ScopeDuration createScopeDuration(T &&t, const char *location)
{
    return ScopeDurationConstructor(std::forward<T>(t), location);
}
#define LOG_SCOPE_DURATION(category_arg) NS::createScopeDuration(category_arg, __func__)
```

Usage:

```
 auto scope = LOG_SCOPE_DURATION(argument);
```

This is basically the ScopeDurationConstructor function.

Hopefully from C++20 on, you could use [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location), which is constexpr.
In that case, you could write:

```
template<typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr ScopeDuration createScopeDuration(T &&t, const std::source_location& location = std::source_location::current()))
{
    return ScopeDurationConstructor(std::forward<T>(t), location.function_name());
}
```

Usage:

```
auto scope = createScopeDuration(argument);
```

Again, you can include this all in the constructor of ScopeDuration.

Note that this feature was approved for C++20, however, the wording has not yet been added to the standard. See the [trip report](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/au0c4x/201902_kona_iso_c_committee_trip_report_c20/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

> Possible to get value of `__func__` in a constexpr?

Yes.

> Is it possible to convert [my macro] into a constexpr?

No. If you use `__func__` in a constexpr function, then you get the name of the constexpr function; you don't get the name of whatever calls the function, which you would get when you expand a pre-processor macro.